# How to unit test a function which as viewchild

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a scenario where I need to test a function which as `@Viewchild` reference.

**My component.ts**

```
    @ViewChild('accTitle', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) title: ViewContainerRef;
    @ViewChild('accText', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) body: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(
        private renderEngineService: RenderEngineService,
        @Inject(CONTENT_MAPPINGS) private contentMappings: any,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderEntityRanges(this.item);
    }

    renderEntityRanges(item: AreasData) {
        this.item.sections.forEach(section => {
            if (section.type === 'title') {
                this.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(this.title);
            } else if (section.type === 'text') {
                this.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(this.body);
            }
            section.rjf.forEach(rjf => {
                const type = this.contentMappings[rjf.type];
                this.renderEngineService.createComponent(rjf, type);
                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            });
        });
    }
```

So In my Spec file, I did the following

```
  it('should invoke renderEntityRanges', () => {
    const renderEntityRanges = spyOn(accordionItemComponent, 'renderEntityRanges');
    accordionItemComponent.ngAfterViewInit();
    expect(renderEntityRanges).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ACCORDION_ITEM);
  });
```

Above test case works fine.

But I'm now sure how to test this function `renderEntityRanges`.

What it dose is `renderEntityRanges`, it will check for the type in `ACCORDION_ITEM` if `type` is `title`, then will make service call to `this.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef` with input as `this.title`.

So please help how can this function be unit tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct `renderEntityRanges`, I have removed `this.item` to `item` only, as it is being passed as an argument.

```
    renderEntityRanges(item: AreasData) {
        item.sections.forEach(section => {
            if (section.type === 'title') {
                this.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(this.title);
            } else if (section.type === 'text') {
                this.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(this.body);
            }
            section.rjf.forEach(rjf => {
                const type = this.contentMappings[rjf.type];
                this.renderEngineService.createComponent(rjf, type);
                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            });
        });
    }
```

and make `renderEngineService` & `changeDetectorRef` as `public` in **constructor** for spying:

```
public renderEngineService: RenderEngineService,
public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

You can try to test it as:

```
it('should set Container Ref and create component',()=>{
   spyOn(accordionItemComponent.renderEngineService,'setRootViewContainerRef').and.callThrough();
   spyOn(accordionItemComponent.renderEngineService,'createComponent').and.callThrough();
   spyOn(accordionItemComponent.changeDetectorRef,'detectChanges').and.callThrough();
   accordionItemComponent.renderEntityRanges(ACCORDION_ITEM);
   expect(accordionItemComponent.renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(accordionItemComponent.renderEngineService.createComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(accordionItemComponent.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

and make sure `ACCORDION_ITEM` has data which satisfies both `types` and `section.rjf = [ some array to iterate over]`